# Is it safe to use java.util.Timer inside a servlet ?

Tags: java, servlets, multithreading, scheduling, timer

For many reasons, it is not good practice to use threads inside a servlet.

`java.util.Timer` seems like wrapper around a thread. So, is it also not safe to use it?
If so, what is the safest way to schedule a task in a servlet?

Comment: For best answers please elaborate what exactly you do need it for.

Comment: I don't really think it matters, does it ?

Comment: You can certainly use it safely, but the safest (best) way depends on the actual functional requirement. Ones asking this particular question are often not fully aware of the servlet lifecycle, which might lead to problems when you play with threads. That's the root cause of the problem that it is "not a good practice" (which is thus actually not true :) ).

Comment: Crossposted: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10893731#10893731

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use Timers.

One **important** thing to remember is to **cancel that Timer** when the servlet is stopped. If you forget to cancel the Timer, your webapp will suffer from memory leaks (classloader leaks, since the Timer's Thread is bound to the WebappClassLoader via its ContextClassLoader) and cannot be deployed multiple times.

Comment: there is another safe wrapper ?

Comment: define "safe" please. Do you mean "secure access" or "bug-free" or "easy to use" or ...?

Comment: it is very bug-free. most problems with Threads and Timers in applications come from applicaton developers, not from JVM or appserver developers :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's perfectly safe. The servlet container will look after threads for HTTP requests, but you can spawn aditional threads yourself, whether their lifetime is restricted to that of the request, or for longer.

e.g. a common pattern is to spawn a long running processing thread. Servlet requests would put work items on a queue (for out-of-band processing) and the long running processing thread would handle these work items.

[Here's an article from OReilly](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/10/13/j2ee-timers.html?page=2) detailing timer usage in servlets and EJBs.

Comment: even I use it in doPost oe doGet methods ?